# Optimizing code for ATtiny10

Tags: c++, attiny, code-optimization, sketch-size

I'm trying to squeeze code onto an [ATtiny10](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATtiny10), but I'm just not getting there. I'm using 1060 bytes and only have space for 1024 bytes.

The code is simple enough; I need to read a button pin. If high it needs to pick a random value and that causes one of two random LEDs on the PCB to turn on for two seconds. Is there a way to optimize this code to work on this IC?

```
int buttonState = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(3, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    buttonState = digitalRead(3);
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
        bool ranNum=random(0,1);
        if(ranNum == 0) {
            digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
        }
        else {
            digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
        }
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the compiler would optimize out in this situation, but have you tried using direct port manipulation instead of using `digitalWrite()`, `digitalRead()` and `pinMode()`. When not using this the compiler might optimize these functions out.

Comment: Not sure if it helps byte wise but you can change `if(ranNum == 0) {
            digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
        }
        else {
            digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
        }` into `digitalWrite(ranNum == 0 ? 0 : 1, HIGH);`

Comment: I'm unsure about how direct port forwarding works i'll look up some tutorials thanks for the suggestion. The ternary operator doesnt seem to save any bytes good suggestion tho

Comment: `digitalWrite(ranNum & 1, HIGH)` -- also use a `uint8_t` instead of an `int`.

Comment: also also `random()` is a wrapper around `rand()` which probably wastes bytes. Use `rand() & 1` to get a random 1 or 0.

Comment: On such a small device, I would get rid of the Arduino core and program at the [avr-libc](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/index.html) level.

Comment: @EdgarBonet On such a small device I'd get rid of avr-libc and program it in assembly...

Comment: Please take a look at an article I wrote some time ago regarding [AVR code optimizations](https://jpralves.net/post/2015/06/16/avr-optimizations.html).

Comment: Are your pins and pinMode()s correct?  `pinMode(3,INPUT)` seems like the default, and the random HIGHs on 0&1 seem inconsistent with the LOWS on  1&2

Comment: How big is the code if you replace random by a constant?

Comment: Related: *[Optimizing code to use less flash memory and SRAM](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67306/)* and *[What can I do if I run out of flash memory or SRAM?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/221/)*

Comment: Aren't the LEDs quite weak? Isn't the default I/O input? The code as presented here would seem to switch the internal pull-up resistors on and off (as ***none of the I/O pins are set up as output***). Switching the internal pull-up resistors on and off ***will*** produce some light on the LEDs, but not very much. The current through them will only be on the order of 0.1 mA (100 µA). Or is there some kind of driver circuit that makes up for it?

Answer (score 12):

As I stated in a comment, this device would be too small for me to
consider programming it using an Arduino core. I would rather stick with
the avr-libc and direct port manipulation:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = _BV(PB0)   // PB0 as output
         | _BV(PB1);  // PB1 as output
    for (;;) {
        loop_until_bit_is_set(PINB, PB3);  // wait for PB3 high
        if (rand() & 1)
            PORTB |= _BV(PB1);  // PB1 high
        else
            PORTB |= _BV(PB0);  // PB0 high
        _delay_ms(2000);
        PORTB &= ~_BV(PB0);     // PB0 low
        PORTB &= ~_BV(PB1);     // PB1 low
    }
}
```

This is plain C, but I expect it to be accepted by the Arduino IDE as a
valid .ino file. I tried compiling it like this:

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=attiny10 -Os -Wall -Wextra -DF_CPU=8000000 prog.c -o prog.elf
```

And it resulted in a program that uses 660 bytes of flash. Most of that
is in the implementation of `rand()` and its dependencies
(multiplication and division routines).

Comment: If `rand()` is really taking up that much space, you could probably save a lot of it by using a more compact RNG. [Here's one of my favorites](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bob-jenkins-small-prng-passes-practrand.html), which should run fine on an ATTiny and probably generate better randomness too.

Comment: You could even use the LSB noise of the ADC to generate a random number. Works pretty well from my experience.

Answer (score 7):

If the button is pressed by a human and your clock is high enough (MHz range), you can use a trick and get rid of the RNG.

You can replace it with a free running counter like this:

```c
unsigned char count = 0;

void loop() {

    count += 1;

    buttonState = digitalRead(3);

    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
        if( (count & 1) == 0) {
            digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
        }
        else {
            digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
        }
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    }
}
```

You have `count` incremented every ⪝10 us (depending on your clock speed, attiny executes one instruction per cycle), so when the user pushes the button, the counter will be sampled.

Note: I assumed `loop()` is all what the microcontroller has to do, and it's constantly called.

Comment: That's better randomness than an RNG.  Since delay and its clock is running, you could use its TCNT0 or TCNT0L instead of `count` and get faster counting at zero cost.

Comment: Neither loop() nor digitalWrite() may not even be called. The underlying GCC compiler is pretty good at inlining, optimising them down to single assembly instructions.

Comment: What does it matter, if the function was inlined or not in this context? At the end the function code gets executed, regardless if the compiler inlined it or not.

Comment: @next-hack: Function calls are instructions which use up valuable flash space (and need time to execute).

Comment: @Michael, I think I quite know that... Still, what's the connection between Redy000's answer and the fact that loop() or DigitalWrite() might be inlined, or implemented as an actual branch ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the pins are correct?

Maybe use a smaller random number generator per https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/18092/6628 ?

```
static uint8_t lfsr = 0x01;
const byte LFSR_MASK = 0x8e;

void setup() {
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
  //      int buttonState = digitalRead(3);
  if (digitalRead(3)) {
    if (generateNoise()) {
      digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
    }
    //delay(2000)
    //for (int i = 31; i; i--)_delay_us(64516);
    _delay_ms(2000);
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    digitalWrite(1, LOW);
  }
}


uint8_t generateNoise() {
  // Return 1 bit of noise using a Galois Linear Feedback Shift Register
  // See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register#Galois_LFSRs

  if (lfsr & 1) {
    lfsr =  (lfsr >> 1) ^ LFSR_MASK ;
    return (1);
  }
  else         {
    lfsr >>= 1;
    return (0);
  }
}
```

The RNG didn't help as much as changing the much-disparaged delay.

Comment: Your linear feedback register seems indeed quite efficient space-wise. Plugging it into my implementation of the program reduced its size from 660 to 142 bytes!

Comment: Great. You could probably afford go to a 16 or 32 bit random state variable for richer randomness.

Answer (score 1):

An 8-bit chip requires multiple instructions for processing 16 bit. Changing ints to either uint8_t or int8_t will save code.

Depending on compiler optimization, replacing

```
if ( (count & 1) == 0) {
    digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
}
else {
    digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
}
```

with

```
digitalWrite((count & 1), HIGH);
```

could save bytes.

Comment: I tried the optimization you suggest on an Uno. It saved two bytes.